# Cmake changes breaking builds

Tags: cmake

When I install a library, it goes to `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}`.
When I `find_package(` a library, it searches `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}`.

In windows, [cmake 3.6](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` defaults to `c:\Program Files`.  This has worked well. However in [cmake 3.7](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX.html) `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` defaults to `c:\Program Files\${PROJECT_NAME}`.

Now when I install library `A`, it goes to `C:\Program Files\A`.
When I `find_package(` library `A` from library `B`, it searches `C:\Program Files\B`.

Now I can't find my dependancies anymore.  If I need to specify the exact path `A` was installed to, then I really don't get anything out of `find_package(` anymore.  Am I missing something?

Comment: What is the path (relative to installation prefix) to `*Config.cmake` file for library *A*? By default `find_package()` doesn't search under `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}`; do you specify this directory explicitely?

Comment: @Tsyvarev `find_package(A)` runs `FindA.cmake` which is a file in `${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH}`.  These often provided by libA and use `find_path( PATHS ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX} )`.

Comment: This code and description change situation a lot: I expected that *config* mode of `find_package` is used for find the library, not a **module** mode. It seems that @skypjack in his answer assumes the same: option *PATH_SUFFIXES* is for *config* mode only. By the way, as you use CMake for build and install `A` library, why do not provide `*Config.cmake` with that installation? Usually, `Find*.cmake` scripts are used when providing `*Config.cmake` for the package is not possible. In any case, add information from your comment **into the question post itself**: as I said, it is meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_package.html) of `find_package`, you can use `PATH_SUFFIXES` to do that.

As an example, you can use something like this from `B`:

```
find_package(A REQUIRED PATH_SUFFIXES A)
```

Otherwise you can change `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` for `A` as it follows:

```
if(WIN32)
    if(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT)
        set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX " C:\Program Files" CACHE PATH "..." FORCE)
    endif()
endif()
```

See [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT.html#variable:CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX_INITIALIZED_TO_DEFAULT) for further details.